# Loading a Remote Angular component to an iframe or with another method, inside an Angular App?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, server-side, devextreme

I have an `Angular 6` App that needs to load a component at runtime that is not known by the App.

Basically what I would like to achieve here is to have a bunch of different components running on remote servers. Then when the App needs one of these components, it can load it without having to know the component at design time.

Currently, all these components are compiled within the app and I am using the factory paradigm that is available in Angular `ComponentFactoryResolver`, but like I said, I would like to load these components from a remote server.

I already took a look at universal apps, but I did not find a solution.

I also looked at loading external scripts and run these inside a `<script>` tag, but I don't think that's it.

So, I believe `iframe` tags could help me with this, but I'm not sure. If anyone was confronted with such problem in the past, help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might take a look at: https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/07/29/angular-elements-part-ii-lazy-and-external-web-components.aspx

Comment: It looks like what I want to achieve! Thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help.

Comment: Hello @Brandon, if you have read this post, do you have an idea on how to pass arrays to the external component? In the post he uses setAttributes to pass numbers

Comment: no I haven't read the entire article.